# An algorithm for Generating Random Holes on a grid

Tags: c#, algorithm, grid

I'm trying to make an "Explosion effect on a grid", and I need an algorithm that will allow me to do the following:
[image]

*Note: The grid represents a List<List>, and I'm trying to filter out the red dots*

So we start off with a given grid with black dots (in our case, black dots represent solid points on our grid, and red dots represent the points we remove from the list)

Eventually, our ractangle transformed into this random shape with holes on the edges (blue area)

**My Attempt:**[image]

**The Problem:**
Sometimes the radius of my star/circle shape is pretty big and the output doesn't give me that "explosion" effect I'm looking for (basically, an unpredictable output), plus it really limits the shape.

Do you have any ideas or know of some mathematical algorithms that can help? Thanks for reading! :)

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but this is basically what I'm looking for: [image]

Comment: The trouble with the question is there is no definite way to know what you are looking for, apart from trying something and you giving a yes or a no

Comment: Transform my initial List<List<T>> to a new list without the red dots inside of it

Comment: Can you describe your business task, rather than part of your plan? For example, is it for a game or some other purpose? Is it final output which describes result of explosion or just a timelapse part of it expanding in room? Based on this there is multiple optimal approaches, starting from filtering, ending with just plain pre-drawn "template" caching which will suffice and be most optimal in terms of CPU activity.

Comment: It's for a game. I'm only interested in the final output. As for performance, the grid is rather small (10X10 max) so it doesn't neccessarly have to be the most efficient algorithm

Comment: @eocron I think I was being too vague. Check out the last Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward approach to get template:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int size = 10;
            var grid = GetExplosionTemplate(size, new Random(),1);

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(grid[i + j * size] ? "X" : "O");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

        private static bool[] GetExplosionTemplate(int size, Random rnd = null, float explosionRoughness = 0)
        {
            var grid = new bool[size * size];
            var rr = (size + 1) / 2f;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                        var cellId = i + j * size;
                        var r = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(i - size / 2, 2) + Math.Pow(j - size / 2, 2)) + rnd?.NextDouble()*explosionRoughness ?? 0;
                        grid[cellId] = r > rr;
                }
            }
            return grid;
        }
    }
}
```

Roughness above 1 will give scattered inside explosion, below will give more round explosion. Value around 0.5 to 1.5 is great looking for both even/non-even values. You can play around to make it better looking, honestly for explosion physics I rather choose this roughness based on material in cell (sand penetration is better than stone, for example), cause you don't want fully fledged physics where you calculate explosion power traveling across weighted by resistance cells (for example, explosion in cave will travel along empty paths and slightly destruct environment, rather than create vacuum in radius)

Another simple approach to actually simulate explosion physics is to use recursion. You start at center with explosion power equal to some value, than as you travel wide, each cell will consume some part of that power (and may be destroyed in process), than equaly emits left part of its power to adjacent cells (even visited, so you simulate explosion wave). This way it will be more realistic in terms of materials. You can even simulate partially empty cell from resistance materials (like, iron fence, it is resistant but emits better and destroy everything around)

Comment: Much Appreciated! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Just out of sheer curiousity: what was your thinking process? Like how did you determine that you have to square root these number in that fashion?

Comment: draw a circle in the center with fixed radius => draw a circle in the center with fixed+/-random(0,1) radius.